# The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Promise

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am generating sitemap in next js but getting error as:

```
$ node ./scripts/generate-sitemap.mjs
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Promise
    at writeFileSync (node:fs:2239:5)
    at generate (file:///D:/Github/ashokseeds-website/scripts/generate-sitemap.mjs:44:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

My complete code for file: `scripts/generate-sitemap.mjs`

```
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { globby } from 'globby';
import prettier from 'prettier';

async function generate() {
    const prettierConfig = await prettier.resolveConfig('./.prettierrc.js');
    const pages = await globby([
        'pages/*.js',
        'data/**/*.mdx',
        '!data/*.mdx',
        '!pages/_*.js',
        '!pages/api',
        '!pages/404.js',
    ]);

    const sitemap = `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        ${pages
            .map((page) => {
                const path = page
                    .replace('pages', '')
                    .replace('data', '')
                    .replace('.js', '')
                    .replace('.mdx', '');
                const route = path === '/index' ? '' : path;

                return `
              <url>
                  <loc>${`https://www.ashokseedplant.com${route}`}</loc>
              </url>
            `;
            })
            .join('')}
    </urlset>
    `;

    const formatted = prettier.format(sitemap, {
        ...prettierConfig,
        parser: 'html',
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-sync
    writeFileSync('public/sitemap.xml', formatted);
}

generate();
```

Comment: `formatted = await prettier.format(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

${route}I'm going to post an answer to this as people are likely coming here from (Leerob's Article)[https://leerob.io/blog/nextjs-sitemap-robots], specifically on how to generate dynamic sitemaps for static NextJS sites.

An updated version of his code is below.
Don't forget to install `globby` and `prettier`.

```js
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { globby } from 'globby';
import prettier from 'prettier';
const YOUR_URL = "https:yourUrl.com";
 
async function generate() {
  const prettierConfig = await prettier.resolveConfig('./.prettierrc.js');
  const pages = await globby([
    'pages/*.js',
    'data/**/*.mdx',
    '!data/*.mdx',
    '!pages/_*.js',
    '!pages/api',
    '!pages/404.js',
  ]);
 
  const sitemap = `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        ${pages
          .map((page) => {
            const path = page
              .replace('pages', '')
              .replace('data', '')
              .replace('.js', '')
              .replace('.mdx', '');
            const route = path === '/index' ? '' : path;
 
            return `
              <url>
                  <loc>${`${YOUR_URL}${route}`}</loc>
              </url>
            `;
          })
          .join('')}
    </urlset>
    `;
 
  const formatted = await prettier.format(sitemap, {
    ...prettierConfig,
    parser: 'html',
  });
 
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-sync
  writeFileSync('public/sitemap.xml', formatted);
}
 
generate();
```